# Не коннектится слот Qt5

Tags: c++, qt

Задача с вероятно очень глупой ошибкой перенесенная на тестовый проект:

сделать так что бы кнопка на форме (`MainWindow`) вызвала метод 
класса (`nnn`) `void buttonEdit` который в свою очередь при помощи emit вызывает сигнал `addPush`. Его принимает в `MainWindow` слот `PUSH` и делает все то что спланировано. Проблема в том что при создании слота:

```
connect(n, &nnn::addPush, this, &MainWindow::PUSH);
```

выдает следующее:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и да, если еще коннектить старым способом (с Qt4), то выдает следующее:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код MainWindow.h:

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H
#include <QMainWindow>
#include "nnn.h"

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();
    void setButtonTextFor2Form(QString S);
private slots:
    void on_pushButton_2_clicked();
public slots:
    void PUSH();
private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    nnn* n;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

MainWindow.cpp:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include "form.h"


MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    nnn *n = new nnn();

    connect(n, &nnn::addPush, this, &MainWindow::PUSH);

}
MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_2_clicked()
{

    n->buttonEdit();

}

void MainWindow::PUSH()
{
    ui->pushButton->setText("эта кнопка должна быть нажата");
}
```

nnn.h:

```
#ifndef NNN_H
#define NNN_H

#include <QObject>



class nnn: QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    nnn();
    void buttonEdit();
signals:
    void addPush();
};

#endif // NNN_H
```

nnn.cpp:

```
#include "nnn.h"


nnn::nnn()
{

}

void nnn::buttonEdit()
{
    emit addPush();
}
```

Comment: class nnn: public QObject

Comment: собственно в тексте ошибки все написано

Comment: @Bearded да, я просто не указал модификатор доступа при наследовании QObject, спасибо